# Angular js:Dynamic values as string in ng-model within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am generating a form dynamically in my application. The fields of the forms are the column names in the database table.The user of this application will just pass the name of the table and the skeleton for CRUD application will be prepared dynamically.

In the view part I want to achieve something like this

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key,col) in cols">
    <label for="{{::col}}">{{::col | uppercase | replaceUnderscore}}</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text"  ng-model="{{::col}}"  required />
</div>
```

In the ng-model I just need the string value that is, if the column name is Username then model value should be something like `ng-model="username"` and the value should not be displayed in the form field. So I want to achieve kind of one way data binding.

Comment: When you have `ng-model="username"` is the input value the actual username? i.e. *johndoe*?

Comment: the col array has all the column names i just need to write ng-model="whatever column name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a JS object, for example `$scope.data = {}`, and then `ng-model="data[col]"`.